# Saving object state between foldlevel calls

Tags: buffers, folding, setlocal

I am trying to implement a custom folding function in a way that precomputes all the folds in a single pass and then reports the required foldlevels as needed. To do so, I use a single dictionary that keeps the state and provides functions to work with its internals (inspired by [this](http://bling.github.io/blog/2013/08/16/modularizing-vimscript/), [this](http://ujihisa.blogspot.cz/2010/11/something-like-closure-for-vim-script.html), etc.)

However, unless I am constantly updating the foldexpr as the file changes, I don't get any folding done (foldexpr keeps the older version of the passed dictionary / function?..) (see ex. below)

I wonder if there is a good way to implement this.

```
function! foldclass#new()
  let obj = {}
  let obj.foldlist = []

  function! obj.updatefolds()
    let self.foldlist = []
    let curline = 1
    let totlines = line('$')
    let curdepth = 0
    while curline <= totlines
      let theline = getline(curline)
      if theline =~? '\v.*function.*\(.*\)'
        let curdepth = curdepth + 1
      endif
      let self.foldlist = self.foldlist + [curdepth]
      if theline =~? '\v.*endfunction.*'
        let curdepth = curdepth - 1
      endif
      let curline = curline + 1
    endwhile
  endfunction

  function! obj.folder(lnum)
    if len(self.foldlist) == 0
      echom 'Still empty...'
      return 0
    endif
    return self.foldlist[a:lnum - 1]
  endfunction

  return obj
endfunction

let b:bufobj=foldclass#new()
setlocal foldmethod=expr
setlocal foldexpr=b:bufobj.folder(v:lnum)

augroup autocmds
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufWritePost *.vim call b:bufobj.updatefolds()
  "autocmd BufWritePost *.vim setlocal foldexpr=b:bufobj.folder(v:lnum)
augroup end
```

- If I source the file as is, I get "Still empty..." in messages, but
  echo b:bufobj shows that the foldlist is indeed updated based on the
  file changes.
- If I uncomment the second to last line, it works as intended.

Comment: Relying on correct reference counting is essentially asking for segfaults.  Making `obj` a global variable would make a world of difference in terms of safety, but it will kill your warm, fuzzy feelings about writing OOP scripts in Vim. :)

Comment: @SatoKatsura, how so? Isn't it simply that as long as you have a buffer opened, you will have an associated variable?

But the thought of just having one global dictionary repopulated on each WinEnter or some other event doesn't horrify me:)

Comment: Variables local to functions are deleted when they're no longer referenced.  The bookkeeping involved is complicated, and every time there's a change that involves reference counting there are 3-4 subsequent patches that fix related segfaults.  Most recently this happened when "true" lambdas were added.  With a global variable you have less chances of the corresponding counter going to 0 too early. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you don't need object-oriented features for this simple use case, and you're shooting yourself in the foot with its complexities.

**Edit**: My first hunch was wrong, the `dict` attribute is not necessary here.

Try developing a procedural version first, and get that to work. Only then you may consider converting this to an OO version.

Your code works for me, though. You could try setting a breakpoint in your functions (`:breakadd`), or `:set verbose=20 | normal! zx` and see what gets executed.

Comment: It doesn't fix that for me - still the same problem.
Regarding the help, thanks for the information. The next paragraph there also mentions:

  <blink>
To avoid the extra name for the function it can be defined and directly
assigned to a Dictionary in this way: >
 :let mydict = {'data': [0, 1, 2, 3]}
 :function mydict.len()
 :   return len(self.data)
 :endfunction
 :echo mydict.len()

The function will then get a number and the value of dict.len is a |Funcref| that references this function. ...
  </blink>

Comment: Hm, I `:edit foldclass.vim`, then `:so %`, then `:w` once. Then the b:bufobj is populated. `zx` forces a foldupdate, and then I see the functions folding.

Comment: This is weird.. same sequence of commands, no effect.
b:bufobj was always populated for me, without _dict_ as well, but the output of 
`:echo foldlevel(3)` is 0,
while `echo b:bufobj.folder(3)` is 1

Comment: Which Vim version do you use? I have tried both Vim 7.4.046 and the latest patchlevel.

Comment: I tried with both 7.4.2296 (which I compiled with a different python, so I also checked) 7.4.1724 installed some time ago via homebrew.

Comment: Actually, your original code also works for me; my assumptions was wrong. I still don't know what's wrong on your side, though. Tested with a vanilla Vim: `vim -N -u NONE`.

Comment: Huh, indeed! It also works for me with default settings - must be some setting or plugin. Thank you!